# Render controller action from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rendering, ruby-on-rails-3

I think the code is more explicit

## option A

```
class RedirectController < ApplicationController
  def index
    redirect_to :controller => 'posts', :action => 'show', :id => 1
    # it works
  end
end
```

## option B

```
class RedirectController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render :controller => 'posts', :action => 'show', :id => 1
    # it doesn't work
  end
end
```

Is possible in (B) to load another action in another controller? (and not just the view) How?
Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It might be better if you tell us the underlying problem that you are trying to solve.

Comment: The "underlying problem" is that i want to be free to set up some urls as I wish without touching routes.rb

Comment: Just to clarify, your Option A does not render an action from another controller, it answers the current request with a redirect that points the browser to the other controller (therefore results in a second request that hits the other controller). `render :template => 'posts/show'´ however really renders the template of the other controller directly. Of course you need to set up stuff for the template to display (like your @post var).

I'm not sure if I understand what you're trying to do, but usually you cannot set up urls without touching routes.rb, since that's what routes.rb is good for.

Comment: yes if you don't want to assign @post var you should user "redirect_to" because if you use "render" then code in your action aren't executed "render" just renders other view file with current data to fiil in

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try `render 'posts/show'` or `render :template => 'posts/show'`

Comment: Thanks it works in both ways but it isn't very clean because I had to add @post ..

    @post = Post.find 1
    render 'posts/show'

Comment: This works, but doesn't render the other controller's template around the action template. Is there a way to force that?

Comment: you can force the layout with `:layout =>` option

Comment: This renders the thing associated with the route 'posts/show', it doesn't render the #show action from the #posts controller.  Those are two completely different ideas that often overlap.

Comment: Imagine the following line in routes.rb: get 'posts/show', controller: :something_else, action: :erase_the_database.  Or imagine a routes.rb that doesn't have a route for posts/show.  The question was very specific: it wanted to render a controller/action pair, not a route.  (Having said that, I think your answer is useful, even if it's not really an answer to the question that was asked.)

Answer (score 7):

Just render the template

```
def index
  render 'posts/show'
end
```

This one also works

```
def index
  render template: 'posts/show'
end
```

If you want to render in some other layout

```
def index
  render template: 'posts/show', layout: 'different_layout' 
end
```