# Rails - Render function from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, renderpartial

I have a route where the url `facebook/get/:id` will render a partial, with no layout, of the profile of a person from Facebook with the given id.
The function `facebook#get` expects `param[:id]` to be set with the id of a profile.

In a different controller I wish to use the partial generated above with out repeating the code found in `facebook#get` but I am struggling.
I have tried variations of `render :template => "facebook/get"` & `render :action => "facebook/get"` but nothing is working.

Is it best to figure out how to render this function or just copy the code to the new controller?

Comment: like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3370372/1301840)?

Comment: @lusketeer not exactly, I want the code in `facebook#get` to be ran, which this does not do

Comment: not sure I follow, why not just use the same partial in the desired controller action view, and just pass in the object as one of the `locals`, post some codes of controllers and partials would help